# YUV video to Images. Find the end of the video?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, yuv

I am using this [Function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318-convert-yuv-cif-4-2-0-video-file-to-image-files) to convert YUV video to images. It reads the video, frame by frame and works fine. 
I am looping through all the frames and have to stop at the end when all the frames have been read. Problem is that it doesn't tell me that end is reached and keeps on displaying frames in a circular manner i.e after last frame comes the first and so on. if I can somehow know the total number of frames I can break the loop.

```
function[intensity_array] = roi()
intensity_array = [];
for i=1:1000000000
    try
        image = loadFileYuv('D:\test_data\test_ardu_2sec_short.yuv',320,240,i);
        roi = image.cdata([37:52],[278:290],1);  % y,x row, column
        max_red_intensity = max(max(roi));
        intensity_array(end+1) = max_red_intensity;
    catch
        intensity_array(end+1) = 0;
        break
    end    
    disp(['iter:', num2str(i)]);
end
end
```

I see that once the last frame is reached there is some error(below) and then the cycle begins again. So Can I break there ?

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in loadFileYuv (line 18)
    imgYuv(:, :, 1) = reshape(buf, width, height).'; % reshape
```

P.S: It's not a matlab in-built function but an open source one so maybe not many people know how it operates. But you can surely get an idea from its code.

Comment: Please add example code to your question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `loadFileYuv` uses `fseek` with absolute values to jump to a specific frame in the file, it can not repeat frames. There is probably an error in your code.

Comment: edited the question with code. Please check

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behaviour you described, it's not displaying any frame.

Comment: `image = loadFileYuv('D:\test_data\test_ardu_2sec_short.yuv',320,240,i);` in above code `i` represents the frame number. If it exceeds the total number of frames still some value is returned. Check for any arbitrary `i` What is that ?

Comment: Okay, there it returns a frame (not displaying it) but I don't see anything repeating. It runs until the end of file is reached, then it exits with an error.

Comment: ya it returns a structure with cdata and colormap. For display I used `imshow` function and visually its repeating. I can vouch for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73746/discussion-between-coderaemon-and-daniel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any valid inputs `loadFileYuv` returns the correct output. So fix your code, not passing any invalid frame indices. Your loop should end at:

```
s=dir('D:\test_data\test_ardu_2sec_short.yuv')
num_of_frames=s.bytes/1.5/320/240
```

With a resolution of 320*240 you have 320*240 Y-Pixes. For U and V per definition the resolution reduced by a factor of 4 to 160*120. So you have 1.5*320*240 pixels with 1 byte each.

For to large frame indices, the function always returns the first frame. This is cause because the return value of `fseek` isn't checked.

To make the function more robust, replace line 15 with:

```
assert(0==fseek(fileId, (idxFrame(f) - 1) * sizeFrame, 'bof'),'fseek failed, probably end of file is reached');
```

Comment: The method to calculate total number of frames (by size of each pixel) is an approximation or is it precise ? But it does fail after that frame number so it verifies that.

Comment: I added some explanations to my answer.